# PHP MySQL Query Question / Help - Joining tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to help to show wall posts from the friends of the logged in user, and the user himself ofc.. :P
I've searched on every coding forums, and google, did not find the answer I was looking for :/

The Session for the logged in user are:

```
$_SESSION['userid']
```

This is the MySQL Query I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM status_updates JOIN friends ON status_updates.member_id = friends.friend_with LEFT JOIN members ON status_updates.member_id = members.member_id ORDER BY status_id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

The query outputs the Status Update from the friends right, but when it comes to the logged in user, the Status Update get duplicated, here's what it looks like:
http://i30.tinypic.com/29bkqaw.png

There is only two entries in status_updates, one for **Test Bruker 4** and one for **Endre Hovde**..

I'm logged in as Endre Hovde by the way.

---

I'll be thankful for any help I can get, credz for the best answer ;)
Thanks in advance! :)

// Endre Hovde @ **rCon^**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
$query = "select su.* 
          from status_updates su 
          where 
               su.member_id in (
                  select " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " as member_id
                  UNION 
                  select fr.member_id 
                  from friends fr
                  where exists (select 1 from friends
                                where member_id = fr.member_id
                                and friend_with = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ")

               )
          order by su.status_id desc limit 0,10";
```

Comment: Drop the "s" in friends_with, and it works perfect! :D

thank you very much ;)
Credz to you!

Comment: Cool.. glad I could help.  I love SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will get a duplicate for the same answer for every friend a user has. You have to split up your request in several parts, or you use a unique ID (preferably the comment ID) to group them with PHP. That can be achieved easily using an array and using the comment ID as the key for that array.